# Fetch data in database always display first record

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007

When i search differennt building number in search box it always display first record in the table.
When i tried diffrent building number it does now display it always stay first record of the table.

Can anybody correct my code. Thanks.

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 
    
        OleDbConnection con2 = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\Users\test\TDB.accdb");

        try
          {

            con2.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con2;
            string query = "select * from TestDatabase where Building_No='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Building_No", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Building_Name", textBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year_", textBox2.Text);



            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           if (reader.Read())
            {
       
                textBox4.Text = reader["Building_Name"].ToString();
                textBox2.Text = reader["Year_"].ToString();
           



            }
     
        }
          catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Reference # found!", "Error");
            textBox4.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post what data you have in your table and what parameter for textBox1.Text?

Comment: You're adding three parameters to your command but there are no parameters in your SQL code, so what's the point? There's only one criterion in your `WHERE` clause too so, even if you were using parameters properly, you'd only be able to use one. I suggest that you do a bit more reading and learn how to use parameters properly. You really ought to use `Add` rather than `AddWithValue` too.

Comment: Building_Name : Serpin Construction             Building_No : 53346                                          Year_ : 2014

Comment: You want to show all the records of search result? where you want to sow them? in textbox? in gridview? you are reading only first record from the reader and assign thrm to textboxes in your code.

Comment: Hi yes i want to show all record of search result in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

If the result of 'OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader' is multiple rows

You must call OleDbDataReader.Read() multiple.

example:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader["Building_Name"].ToString());
}
```

e.g.

```
textBox4.Text = "";
while (reader.Read())
{
    textBox4.Text += reader["Building_Name"].ToString() + ",";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It could be because you didn't close the **connections**. Can you try the code below?

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OleDbConnection con2 = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\Users\test\TDB.accdb");

    try
    {

        con2.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con2;
        string query = "select * from TestDatabase where Building_No='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Building_No", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Building_Name", textBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year_", textBox2.Text);

        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            textBox4.Text = reader["Building_Name"].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = reader["Year_"].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        con2.Close();
 
    }
      catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Reference # found!", "Error");
        textBox4.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi it same . Only show first record of table